# Data binding a value with @ symbol in polymer 0.5 template

Tags: polymer

In my polymer 0.5 webapp I', using multiple core-menus such as the following:

```
           <core-menu id="drawermenu">
                <template repeat="{{p in menuItems}}">
                    <paper-item>
                        <div>
                            <core-icon icon="{{p.icon}}"></core-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-left:20px" flex>{{p.name}}</div>
                    </paper-item>
                </template>
            </core-menu>
```

The menuItems array I'm listing data from is pulled into my javascript with a database query and also contains the value "@rid" for every object in the array.  If it was just called "rid" I could list it like any other value, but the @  makes things difficult. I cannot just call "{{p.@rid}}".

So how do I call that value in my template?

Comment: Have you tried `"{{p['@rid']}}`?

Comment: l thought I had, honestly, but for whatever reason it appears I hadn't, because this works perfectly. Thanks very much!  :-)